# Color image to grayscale image with Raphael.js not working in I.E. 9

Tags: css, image, filter, raphael, grayscale

I have some images that I show with the Raphael library. The foremost reason I have choosen the Raphael library is because it is supported in many browsers.  My problem now is representing the images in black and white (grayscale). I have managed  to do show them in grayscale in Chrome, FF, Safari, I.E 6.0+. But for some reason it is not working in the I.E 9.0.

The code i use is following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
    #mainImg { 
        filter: url(filter.#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */ 
        filter: grayscale; /* IE5+ */ 
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
    } 
</style> 
</head>    

<body>
   <svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
       <filter id="grayscale"> 
            <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" /> 
        </filter> 
   </svg>     

<div id="pItem"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

 var paper= Raphael(document.getElementById("pItem"), 600, 400, "#c0c0c0");

 var pSet = paper.set();

 var c = paper.image("images/img1.png", 0, 0, 200 ,300);
     c.node.id = 'mainImg'; 

     c.node.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)';


    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the `.` in `filter.#grayscale` a typo, or is the syntax derive from the SVG being embedded in the document?

Comment: another one: try `filter: gray;` instead of `filter: grayscale;` for IE5+, just to narrow down the possible issues.

Comment: It is the syntax derive from the SVG being embedded in the document.

Answer (score 2):

we know IE9 support for SVG spec is lacking, as [features like `foreignObject` are not covered](http://schmerg.com/svg-support-in-ie9-close-but-should-try-harde), preventing it from being fully standards compliant.

after running the [W3C designated test for SVG color filter](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20030813/htmlframe/full-filters-color-01-b.html) it is official that support for the `matrix` filter type is also lacking at the moment.

here's a snapshot made by [IE netrenderer](http://netrenderer.com/), fed with the above linked test page:
[image: svg filter matrix test on ie9]

it can also be seen by running the [CanIUse test](http://tests.caniuse.com/?feat=svg-filters&ua=ie9&prefix=all).

Comment: Is there an another way for representing the SVG in grayscale without
using the matrix filter for IE9.